# GWT Graphics - resetting the text

Tags: graphics, gwt, vaadin

I am working on a project for which i am using [GWT-Graphics](http://vaadin.com/web/hene/wiki/-/wiki/Main/GWT%20Graphics%20Manual;jsessionid=591AF166DFFD20E90A118E772363AAAE#section-GWT+Graphics+Manual-SettingUpTheLibraryInYourProject). I have drawing Area containing ellipse and text. When i double click on them a pop-up menu appears and gives an option to enter text. Now when i save this text i want it to appear on this drawing area in the place of the previous text.

I am trying to do this but with no luck. It keeps the old text and on top of that it includes the current text. Is there a way to have only the new text to appear.

Any input will be of great help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this sounds like that you are adding a new Text element instead of using the existing one. I wrote a quick test and it seems to work like you want:

```
public class GwtTest2 implements EntryPoint {

    private Text text;

    public void onModuleLoad() {

        DrawingArea da = new DrawingArea(400, 400);
        RootPanel.get().add(da);
        da.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                String newTextValue = Window.prompt("", "");
                text.setText(newTextValue);
            }
        });

        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(200, 200, 100, 50);
        da.add(ellipse);

        text = new Text(150, 200, "Hello world!");
        da.add(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, my project has more than one drawing area and i have to change text on those at different situations. From your example i saw what i was doing wrong. Thank you.